# How to find all possible combinations from nested list containing list and strings?

Tags: python, list

I am trying to get all possible pattern from list like:

```
input_x = ['1', ['2', '2x'], '3', '4', ['5', '5x']]
```

As we see, it has 2 nested list `['2', '2x']` and `['5', '5x']` here.

That means all possible pattern is 4 (2 case x 2 case), the expect output is:

```
output1 = ['1','2' , '3', '4',  '5']
output2 = ['1','2x', '3', '4',  '5']
output3 = ['1','2' , '3', '4', '5x']
output4 = ['1','2x', '3', '4', '5x']
```

I tried to search how to, but I can not find any examples (because of I have no idea about "keyword" to search)

I think python has inner libraries/methods to handle it.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

One way to achieve this is via using [`itertools.product`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html#itertools.product). But for using that, you need to firstly wrap the single elements within your list to another list.

For example, firstly we need to convert your list:

```
['1', ['2', '2x'], '3', '4', ['5', '5x']]
```

to:

```
[['1'], ['2', '2x'], ['3'], ['4'], ['5', '5x']]
```

This can be done via below list comprehension as:

```
formatted_list = [(l if isinstance(l, list) else [l]) for l in my_list]
# Here `formatted_list` is containing the elements in your desired format, i.e.:
#    [['1'], ['2', '2x'], ['3'], ['4'], ['5', '5x']]
```

Now call [`itertools.product`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html#itertools.product) on the unpacked version of the above `list`:

```
>>> from itertools import product

#                v  `*` is used to unpack the `formatted_list` list
>>> list(product(*formatted_list))
[('1', '2', '3', '4', '5'), ('1', '2', '3', '4', '5x'), ('1', '2x', '3', '4', '5'), ('1', '2x', '3', '4', '5x')]
```

Comment: Nice! Also answers my question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/48625379/1348273).

Comment: I am glad to help two question with one answer ;)

Answer (score 0):

If you don't want to convert your list to all sub list then 
You can try something like this :

```
input_x = ['1', ['2', '2x'], '3', '4', ['5', '5x'],['6','6x']]

import itertools
non_li=[]
li=[]
for i in input_x:
    if isinstance(i,list):
        li.append(i)
    else:
        non_li.append(i)



for i in itertools.product(*li):
    sub=non_li[:]
    sub.extend(i)
    print(sorted(sub))
```

output:

```
['1', '2', '3', '4', '5', '6']
['1', '2', '3', '4', '5', '6x']
['1', '2', '3', '4', '5x', '6']
['1', '2', '3', '4', '5x', '6x']
['1', '2x', '3', '4', '5', '6']
['1', '2x', '3', '4', '5', '6x']
['1', '2x', '3', '4', '5x', '6']
['1', '2x', '3', '4', '5x', '6x']
```